# Android: No Activity found to handle Intent error? How it will resolve

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, preferences, onitemclicklistener

No Activity found to handle Intent error? How it will resolve.

```
Preference customPref = (Preference) findPreference("DataEntryScreen"); 
   customPref
        .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
         public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {                  

        Intent i = new Intent("com.scytec.datamobile.vd.gui.android.AppPreferenceActivity");
                 startActivity(i);
                  return true;                                        
               }
           });
```

Comment: have you registered the intent filter (`"com.scytec.datamobile.vd.gui.android.AppPreferenceActivity"`) for the activity in manifiest?

Comment: No . how it can ? please write proper intent ?
i mean to say code

Comment: post your manifest file here, (with the entry corresponding to activity - AppPreferenceActivity). then we can help you with right code.

Comment: <uses-permission 
<application android:name="DataMobileApplication"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:icon="@drawable/sfa"
android:theme="@style/DataMobileTheme">
<activity android:name="Settings"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/DataMobileTheme">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.setting" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

Comment: public class AppPreferenceActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
     }
    }

Comment: the manifest does not have AppPreferenceActivity? you can edit your question to post the manifest file content. Don't use comments section.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Add the below to your manifest:

```
  <activity   android:name=".AppPreferenceActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">  
     <intent-filter> 
       <action android:name="com.scytec.datamobile.vd.gui.android.AppPreferenceActivity" />  
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
     </intent-filter>   
  </activity>
```

Answer (score 21):

in my case, i was sure that the action is correct, but i was passing wrong URL, i passed the website link without the http:// in it's beginning, so it caused the same issue, here is my manifest (part of it)

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyBrowser"
        android:label="MyBrowser Activity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="com.dsociety.activities.MyBrowser" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

when i code the following, the same Exception is thrown at run time :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.dsociety.activities.MyBrowser");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("www.google.com"));    // should be http://www.google.com
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 17):

Generally to avoid this kind of exceptions, you will need to surround your code by try and catch like this

```
try{

// your intent here

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
// show message to user 
}
```

Comment: I disagree. What you should be doing is to check first if the intent can be handled by any activity

`
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
       startActivity(intent);
}
`

Comment: @MarkPazon this works in 99% of the cases but if you have an activity handling a custom scheme, then you could run into a crash if the user is running an old version of the app without the new scheme in the manifest.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null) {
    Utils.showToast(activity, no_app_available_to_complete_this_task);
} else {
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would work for the original question?

Comment: this is example to check that activity available or not with related intent      whatever you user as your requirment  startActivity() or startActivityForResult()               resolveActivity check that any activity/package to handle this intent exist or not

Answer (score 1):

Intent intent=new Intent(String) is defined for parameter task, whereas you are passing parameter componentname into this, use instead:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.this, com.scytec.datamobile.vd.gui.android.AppPreferenceActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

In this statement replace ActivityName by Name of Class of Activity, this code resides in.

Comment: he constructor Intent(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){}, Class<AppPreferenceActivity>) is undefined

Comment: use your first activity name instead of ActivityName instead of this only, as first parameter should be instance of an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

if you handle the activity that couldnt find at another module make sure that you have added below line on your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation project(':YOUR-MODULE-ROOT')
```