# Multiple image picker shows no activity found in android

Tags: android

When I click the button the app crash and shows no activity found.The logcat error shows in the place of startActivityForResults. What to do for starting that activity. Any one give solution to rectify this error.`

```
btnGalleryPickMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Action.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(i, 200);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String[] all_path = data.getStringArrayExtra("all_path");

            ArrayList<CustomGallery> dataT = new ArrayList<CustomGallery>();


            for (String string : all_path) {
                CustomGallery item = new CustomGallery();
                item.sdcardPath = string;

                dataT.add(item);
                //
                String size=item.sdcardPath;
                Log.d("size--", size);
                image1.add(item.sdcardPath);
                Log.d("map--", String.valueOf(image1));


                ArrayList<String> ImgData =image1;
                Log.d("ImgData--", String.valueOf(ImgData));


                for (int i = 0; i < ImgData.size(); i++) {
                    map.add(ImgData.get(i).toString());


                }

            }

            viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
            adapter.addAll(dataT);
//
//            new ImageUploadTask()
//                    .execute(count + "", "pk" + count + ".jpg");
        }
    }
```

**Logcat error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.airstar.abservetech.airstar, PID: 25444
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=luminous.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1687)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1479)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3448)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3409)
at com.airstar.abservetech.airstar.Add_room$5.onClick(Add_room.java:295)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4446)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18437)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5372)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: There is no app on the device that supports that `Intent` action. What makes you think that there should be an app that supports it?

Comment: Have u added `CustomGalleryActivity ` Activity in `AndroidManifest ` ? see following git [luminousman/MultipleImagePick](https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: No Activity found to handle Intent error? How it will resolve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157490/android-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-error-how-it-will-resolve)