# search Intent is not working

Tags: android, android-intent

Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working?

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
    i.setPackage("com.google.android.stardroid");
    i.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "mars");
    startActivity(i);
```

This is in the oncreate method in the main Activity. I haven't added anything else to the manifest.

The error I'm getting is "No Activity found to handle intent"

Comment: Maybe this post should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157490/android-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-error-how-it-will-resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that the app is not installed, or even is it [broken](https://f-droid.org/wiki/page/com.google.android.stardroid)?

Comment: yes you need an actual sky maps app which will receive intent.

Comment: ahh ok that was my issue....Thanks! Is there anyway to get around this? I guess sky maps would need an api..

Comment: What do you mean? The way round it is to make sure the app you want to run is actually installed.

Comment: Sorry, I mean a way around having to have the sky map app installed. I feel it would be a pain for users to have to install both my app and the sky map app

Comment: What does your app do?

Comment: Its an astronomy based app. It will act as a learning tool for amateur astronomers, and I wanted a feature similar to sky map in it, where a user could find a planet they wanted to observe. This wouldn't be that main point of the app, just a side feature.

Answer (score 1):

This should definitely work

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.stardroid");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```