# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ACTIVITY_NOT_FOUND, No Activity found to handle intent { 09829132444 }, null, null)

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

I have a button for mailing user, but when i click button it showing platform exception

```
launchUrl(Uri(path: "mailto:${baseSetting.baseSetting?.mail ?? ''}"))

E/flutter ( 1164): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ACTIVITY_NOT_FOUND, No Activity found to handle intent { mailto%3Asales@sookh.com }, null, null)
E/flutter ( 1164): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter ( 1164): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter ( 1164): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1164): #2      launchUrlString (package:url_launcher/src/url_launcher_string.dart:39:10)
E/flutter ( 1164): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1164): #3      launchUrl (package:url_launcher/src/url_launcher_uri.dart:55:10)
E/flutter ( 1164): <asynchronous suspension>
```

please help how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You may try the answer in this post : [Android: No Activity found to handle Intent error? How it will resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157490/android-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-error-how-it-will-resolve)

but in my app where i got this error, it was due to the emulator i used not having gmail installed on it. upon getting one with gmail everything worked fine(obviously my app is opening gmail and not contacts). so make sure you have yours installed

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following queries in AndroidManifest.xml file above

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

.
.
.
  =>